# How can I plot the derivatives of the components of the solution to a system of ODEs?

Tags: matlab, plot, ode

I have the following MATLAB code for the function solving a system of ODEs:

```
function dwdt=coupled(t,w)
beta=1+exp(-t);
delta=2+exp(-t);
gama=exp(-t);
f1=1/(t+1);
f2=1/(t+2);
r1=1/(t+2)^2;
r2=2/(t+1)^2;
dwdt=zeros(4,1);
dwdt(1)=w(2)-f1*w(1);
dwdt(2)=-beta*w(1)-f1*w(2)+gama*w(3)-r1*w(1)^2;
dwdt(3)=w(4)-f2*w(3);
dwdt(4)=gama*w(1)-delta*w(3)-f2*w(4)-r2*w(3)^2;
xdot=w(2)-f1.*w(1);
end
```

With the commands

```
>> tspan = [0 50];
z0=[0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01];
[t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) coupled(t,z), tspan, z0);
figure
plot(t,z(:,1),'r',t,z(:,3),'b');
legend('x(t)','y(t)');
```

I have plotted the first `w(1)` and the third `w(3)` components of the solution. But I want also to plot on the same interval, with the same initial data, the derivatives of `w(1)` and `w(3)`, i.e., `dwdt(1)=w(2)-f1*w(1)` and `dwdt(3)=w(4)-f2*w(3)`.

If I add the command line

```
plot(t,z(:,2)-f1*z(:,1),'b');
```

I get the message

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'f1'.
```

How `dwdt(1)` and `dwdt(3)` can be plotted ?

Comment: You defined the 'f1' variable within the 'coupled' function. You cannot call it outside the funciton. You must define 'f1' in the main code, before you can call it, 'f1=@(t) 1./(t+1);'

Comment: @Thales Thank you, but I do not understand exactly. Could you please write the main code?

Comment: Use the ODE function to compute the derivatives at the output points, probably with a loop over the `t(i), z(i,:)` pairs. If you chose the dense output option, this is already implemented by the support function `deval`.